# EntityFramework Include (Eager Load) virtual Property of virtual property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Imagine that we have three Dbsets like below:

```
Category
{
...
   public virtual ICollection<Item> Items {get; set;}
...
}

Item
{
...
   public virtual ICollection<Specification> Specifications{get; set;}
...
}

Specification
{
...
}
```

For eager loading I use it like this:

```
Category cat = db.Categories.Include(c=> c.Items).FirstOrDefault(c=> c.Id == 1);
```

but now the problem is that

`cat.Items[0].Specifications` is `null`, How can we make it to eager load sub collections of the collection too?

P.S.: I tried removing the `virtual` keyword for testing (I'm don't want to remove it) but it didn't work either.

Comment: If you do *Go To Definition* in VS for `Include` method, you'll find a whole help topic describing different `Include` scenarios. Basically you need to use `Select`s to navigate down.

Comment: you can use the other Include. the one which takes a string as a parameter. Then you can do something like this: `Include("Items.Specifications")`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also use the notation

```
db.Categories.Include("Items.Specifications")
```

Note it has to be a string

Comment: If you rename "Items" or "Specifications" properties, visual studio will not refactor this string.

Comment: @MariusOrha this is another question. The fact is Mark's solution will work

Answer (score 8):

```
 Category cat = db.Categories
        .Include(c => c.Items.Select(s => s.Specifications))
        .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == 1);
```

Comment: Just wanted to make it clear that virtual has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Yes, the Select part does the duty.

Answer (score 1):

Now we can also use:

```
db.Categories.Include(c => c.Items)
             .ThenInclude(i => i.Specifications);
```